# flutter) I wonder how to get pictures from the gallery

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner who just started programming.
I'm studying while watching an old lecture, but the SDK version used in the lecture is different, so there is an error in the latest version.

I'm creating an app that links with my gallery and prints it on the screen.
This is the code I used.

```
class createPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const createPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _createPageState createState() => _createPageState();
}

class _createPageState extends State<createPage> {
      
  //ImagePicker
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  late File _image; 


  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    createText.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: _buildBody(), 
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getImage,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }


  _buildBody() {
    return SingleChildScrollView( 
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _image == null ? Text("No Image") : Image.file(_image),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _getImage() async {
    //ImagePiker
    var picker_image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = picker_image as File;
    });
  }
```

And when I do debugging, the simulation app has the following errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW1qX.png)

As the version changed, the code also changed a lot. How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: why _getImage() is never called?!

Comment: can you make the `setState` method inside the `_getImage()` function like this: `_image = picker_image.path;`. Documentation is your true friend, not the videos from influencers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is probably the culprit:

```
_image = picker_image as File;
```

ImagePicker.pickImage returns `XFile?`, but you haven't checked whether `picker_image` is non-null before casting it to a `File`.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me by using the version

```
image_picker: ^0.8.4
```

here is my code :

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(CreatePage());
}

class CreatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreatePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreatePageState createState() => _CreatePageState();
}

class _CreatePageState extends State<CreatePage> {
  //ImagePicker
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  File? _image;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // createText.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _buildBody(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _getImage,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildBody() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _image == null ? Text("No Image") : Image.file(_image!),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _getImage() async {
    //ImagePiker
    await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _image = value as File;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some few changes in your code, this is probably occurs in this line i think _image = picker_image as File;

```
   class _createPageState extends State<createPage> {
             
    
         
         File _imageFile;
         final _picker = ImagePicker();
       
         @override
         void dispose() {
           // TODO: implement dispose
           createText.dispose();
           super.dispose();
         }
    
         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return Scaffold(
       
             body: _buildBody(), 
             floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
               onPressed: _getImage,
               backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
               child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
             ),
           );
         }
    
    
         _buildBody() {
           return SingleChildScrollView( 
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 _imageFile == null? Text('No image selected.'): Image.file(_imageFile,fit: BoxFit.cover),
               ],
             ),
           );
         }
    
         Future<void> _getImage() async {
           //ImagePiker
          final image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    
        if (image != null) {
    
        setState(() {
            _imageFile = image;
           });
    
        }else{
           print("No image selected");
         }
           
 }
```